# Вывод комментариев Youtube

Tags: php

Приведите, пожалуйста, пример кода на php, который будет выводить список всех комментариев к определенному видео. С указанием ников. Это реализуется с помощью api

Comment: @Иван Александров, вы знаете, что это реализуется с помощью API, даже, скорее всего, что заглядывали в документацию, но у вас нет желания мучаться, читать её, искать нужное, поэтому решили переложить это на других. Так вас понимать? Вы хоть [по пунктам меню][1] пробегались?

   [1]:https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_comments?hl=ru#Retrieve_comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/123
вместо  123,  - id вашего видео. 
А комментарии парсите.

Comment: спасибо. Это хоть что-то